# trouble with why a variable is taking on a certain value

Tags: if-statement, sas, flags

I am trying to create a variable that will flag (to a "1") when it hits a certain number (when there is improvement in a process).  I am then trying to reset the baseline, so that a new baseline (threshold) has to be hit for it to be flagged.  the data set starts off with just one variable (x).  I create another one from the first observation called "baseline", so I will compare all other "x's" to baseline.  once I hit a threshold, I want to change the baseline to the threshold it just hit.

here is the relevant part of the code (note I have already created code that determined baseline earlier in program).

```
data combo;
set combo;
if (baseline-x)/8 >1 then do;

flag=1;
baseline=x;
end;
else 
flag=0;
run;
```

here is the relevant part of the output.

I am expecting flag to be 1 (which it is) for the third observation (because baseline started out at 259, then moved to 251 as I want it to.  but why is flag=1 after that?  The threshold is not met.     can anyone help?  thanks  John
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another parentheses in your condition like below. 
I run here and after all flags became zero.

```
  if ((baseline-x)/8) >1 then 
        do;
           flag=1;
           baseline=x;
        end;
        else 
        flag=0;
    run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The data step is overwriting the original value of BASELINE after it sets the FLAG variable to 1.  So we cannot see what value it had when read from the original value of the COMBO dataset, but we can assume it was at least 8 more than X to cause it to go down that branch of the IF statement.

Comment: Tom, thanks for response.  Wow.  believe it or not, I have been writing SAS a long time, but I guess I am a novice in some respects.  I do not see how it is overwriting nor the solution.  The way I understand it is that as it reads one line (just two variables), it makes a decision.  On the third line, when baseline had been 259 (its most previous value, from 2nd line), it now sets flag=1, AND resets baseline to 251.  so, on the fourth line, it must be reading baseline as 259 still but I don't see why?  Either way, how can I resolve this?  thanks again

Comment: PS to folowup.  I should have changed the first two 251's to 252's (just to make it clear that the threshold was NOT met... the first few 251's were like 251.3, rounded to 251.  and the third one was 250.8 rounded to 251.  also, I have been getting some very funky results with output on SAS files.  like complete jibberish that I have never seen before.  have you ever seen the SAS environment corrupted?   and it is possible that any corruption is affecting some logic?  thanks

Comment: You need to show the INPUT and the OUTPUT. Do NOT use the same name in the DATA and SET statement, that will overwrite the input with the output.  Also please show data as text, not photographs.  To better see what is happening write the updated values of BASELINE to a NEW variable. Then you can see both values when examining the output dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate variable to keep track of the current baseline. You can use RETAIN to do this.

```
data out;
   set combo;

   ** Keep the value of this for each observation in the data set **;
   retain current_baseline;

   ** Initialize baseline to starting value for data set **;
   if _n_ = 1 then current_baseline = baseline;

   if (current_baseline - x) / 8 < 1 then do;
      flag = 1;
      ** Update current_baseline to new value since flag has been tripped **;
      current_baseline = x;
   end;
   else flag = 0;

   ** If you want to store the value of baseline for later viewing, you can **;
   baseline = current_baseline;

run;
```

Note that you really only need the values of x and the initial baseline value to run this.  Let's say your initial baseline is x - 8.  Then you can simply modify the initialization line to

```
   ** Initialize baseline to starting value for data set **;
   if _n_ = 1 then current_baseline = x - 8;
```

Then you can run this with your raw data set with only the values for x.

Comment: thanks Jeremy, it worked.. I appreciate all responses.  John